# Why is the time constant of RL series circuit be \$\frac{L}{R}\$?

Tags: inductor, time-constant

We all know that the time constant \$\tau_L\$ of RL series circuit is \$\frac{L}{R}\$,and i think there should be an explanation,except the result of circuit simulation, to explain why  the  time constant of RL series circuit is \$\frac{L}{R}\$,why isn't \$\tau_L=RL\$,just like \$\tau_C=RC\$.

Comment: Why? \$L = \frac{V \times t}{I} = \frac{V}{I} \times s = \Omega s \$ and the \$R = \frac{V}{I} = \Omega\$ Therefore \$\tau = \frac{L}{R} = \frac{\Omega s}{\Omega}\ = s\$

Comment: @G36 The \$t\$ is time and \$s\$ is second?or?

Comment: Yes, t is time in seconds.

Comment: The inductance unit is Ohm Seconds \$\Omega s\$(ohms*seconds),

Comment: Notice that for a simple RL circuit at steady-stade the final current is I = V/R because L is short at DC. Thus larger resistance value will decrease the "charging" time (transient time). Because the end current is smaller due to large resistance. Do you see it? And this why L/R is true.

Comment: The solution to the differential equation that governs an R-L circuit dictates the time constant, it has to do with the differential voltage/current relationship of the component.

Comment: @shineele Have you read this? https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-16/why-l-r-and-not-lr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frP2zt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer function of the simple L-R lowpass is

**H(jw)=Vout/Vin=R1/(R1+jwL1)=1/(1+jwL1/R1)**

Now - the factor for the frequency variable L1/R1 is DEFINED as the time constant (and it has the unit "second").

From system theory we know that the step response in the time domain contains an exponential expression **exp(-t*R1/L1)=exp(-t/T1)**.

Now, you can see that after the time **T1=L1/R1** the exponent is "-1". This case DEFINES the time constant: 
**The time constant gives the time which is necessary to bring the step response down to the factor 1/e.**

Answer (score 0):

Because L is proportional to reactance, while C is proportional to admittance.  Large C means more current passes, with everything else the same; large L means less passes.

Answer (score 0):

bigger R causes bigger loses, thus the stored energy is more quickly dissipated.

This fact --- bigger R causes faster losses, thus faster time constant ---- shows up in the differential equation setup and thus in the DE solutions.